# What is it called when some pronounces their "s" sounds sharply

Tags: american-english, british-english, australian-english, literary-english, contemporary-english

I've long noticed that when it comes to pronouncing words containing an "s" sound, their are those that pronounce it softly and those that pronounce it sharply.  I have always wanted to put a name to the latter condition.  Does anyone know what this is called?

Examples: 
 - While whispering in a quiet room, people that speak this way can be heard by a regular "siss siss siss" sound, as they sharply pronounce each word containing an "s" sound, audible despite attempts to be unheard.
 - Words such as "issue" and "controversial" are pronounced with a sharp "sss" instead of "sh".  E.g. "controverSSSial iSSSue" vs "controverSHial iSHue" (admittingly this one could be more geographic in origin). 
- Elongation of sharp "s" sounds, especially at the end of words.  E.g. "issuesss".

I'm certain there is a name for this.  Some might call it simply being eccentric, but I suspect there is a proper linguistic term, which is what I'm interested in foremost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sibilance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant) is the word you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you!  Now I finally have a name for this almost indescribable thing :D